# It is possible to store terraform state file in one aws account and deploy into another using environmental variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to store a terraform state file in one aws account and deploy infrastructure into another. Is it possible to provide different set of credentials for backend and aws provider using environmental variables(`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`)? Or maybe provide credentials to one with environmental variables and another through `shared_credentials_file`?

`main.tf`

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = "=3.74.3"
        }
    }
    backend "s3" {
        encrypt = true
        bucket = "bucket-name"
        region = "us-east-1"
        key = "terraform.tfstate"
    }
}

variable "region" {
    default = "us-east-1"
}
provider "aws" { 
  region                  = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "test" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Comment: You probably could, using aliased providers and profile names.

Comment: @MarkoE there's only 1 AWS provider being used, no need for aliased providers. They just need separate AWS access keys for the provider and the backend.

Comment: Ah, ok, I probably didn't read carefully enough!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the AWS profile/access keys configuration used by the S3 backend are separate from the AWS profile/access keys configuration used by the AWS provider. By default they are both going to be looking in the same place, but you could [configure the backend](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3) to use a different profile so that it connects to a different AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can even keep them in separated files in the same folder to avoid confusion

> backend.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    profile         = "profile-1"
    region          = "eu-west-1"
    bucket          = "your-bucket"
    key             = "terraform-state/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table  = "terraform-locks"
    encrypt         = true
  }
}
```

> main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  profile                 = "profile-2"
  region                  = "us-east-1"
}

resource .......
```

This way, the state file will be stored in the profile-1, and all the code will run in the profile-2